Problems with Polish letters in Cyrillic books when connecting babel (after upgrading LinuxMint)
For many years I have been making Cyrillic books with Polish letters in LaTeX (pdfLaTeX), and I use approximately this preamble. I made the last book a few months ago, after which I upgraded my Linux Mint.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cmap}

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,belarusian]{babel}

Using erewhon, paratype, cochineal and other T2A-friendly fonts (except Computer Modern, which are still fine) gave adequate results for Latin
letters with diacritics.

Now everything looks like this.

I can achieve a similar effect for Latin letters with such a preamble. But then, of course, it is impossible to use Cyrillic.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{erewhon}

\begin{document}
{\Huge ą ł}
\end{document}

I've tried many different fontenc settings, line order combinations, cmap on and off, the newfangled way of specifying babel (in the example below). Overleaf behaves exactly the same way, which I've never used before. I registered there only to check if the problem is in my system. Apparently not. Apparently the problem is in updating some elements of texlive.
\documentclass[belarusian]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{erewhon}

\begin{document}
{\Huge ą ł}
\end{document}

If the changes in the updated packages are stable, I would like to learn how to manage encodings in the new conditions, because I am afraid to make edits to all my books - they will not compile correctly.
inb4: Ahead of the advice to switch to XeLaTex/LuaTeX. If there is no other way out, I will do so. I haven't checked how everything works there yet. Still, I would like to stay in the pdfLaTeX paradigm.

Is there any reason to not use a Unicode-based TeX engine like XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? If you’re already using Unicode inputs, then using Unicode fonts will solve your issues instead of dealing with the hackery that‘s the old 8-bit encodings.

You are right. I am looking at new engines. But pdfLaTeX, which I am used to, still provided the above mentioned capability. And LaTeX is famous for its stability and ability to compile documents of any age. I hope that future package updates will bring back the ability to type utf-8 directly.

Do you know what version of TeX Live you had before? (I don't use Mint but I think it uses a standard TeX Live, more standard than my Ubuntu at any rate)

I can't name the exact version. Now is '2023', before '2021'.

Below, in a conversation with @egreg, it became clear that I am inattentive. :)

You're better to segregate different languages, so LaTeX knows the correct font encoding to use.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% just to avoid an annoying warning
\usepackage[english,polish,belarusian]{babel}

\begin{document}

Беларусь поўная назва Рэспубліка Беларусь дзяржава ва
Усходняй Еўропе, на захадзе Усходне-Еўрапейскай раўніны.

\begin{otherlanguage*}{english}
\foreignlanguage{polish}{Wojciech Szczęsny} is a goalkeeper,
\foreignlanguage{polish}{Krzysztof Piątek} plays forward,
\foreignlanguage{polish}{Jakub Błaszczykowski} played winger.
\end{otherlanguage*}

\end{document}


With erewhon

With paratype


Thank you very much! If I do it this way, everything works.
I must admit that your solution is more authentic, and I was spoiled by the ability to type utf-8 characters directly. Still, I hope that future package updates will bring it back.

@SiaržukKanajeŭski I'm a bit perplexed: this has always been alike. If you state as default font encoding T2A, then accented characters in the Latin alphabet will be composed if the glyphs are available. For other accents, you get what you get.

The letter 'ł' was definitely displayed correctly before.

@SiaržukKanajeŭski Not at all. I tried with TeX Live 2018 (the first one with support for Belarusian and the ł comes out with a different font than Erewhon.

OMG! Just checked the .pdf of the exact book I typed with erewhon. The letter 'ł' was loaded from Computer Modern. So the problem existed before, it just came to light with the update. I was unintentionally misleading you. Thank you again!
